# Axios.PUT не отправляются данные через axios метод PUT на ресурсный роут LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, put

```
              axios.put(url, this.formData, {
                  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
              })
                  .then(response =>{
                          this.open = false;
                          this.$router.push('/posts/'+ this.id)
                  })
                  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

это мой axios запрос,
а вот Route

```
Route::resource('/posts','PostController');
```

И метод Update который не получает данные

```
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdatePostRequest $request, $post)
    {
       $post->fill($request->all());
       if($post->image && $request['file']){
           Storage::delete('/uploads/'.$post->image);
           $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $request['file']->extension();
           $request['file']->storeAs('/uploads',$filename);
           $post->image = $filename;
       }
    }
```

Comment: а разве в роуте не нужно указывать метод? 
```Route::resource('/posts','PostController@update');```

Comment: CORS? Что в консоль говорит?

Comment: Метод при resource не нужно указывать.

Comment: @AlexSazonov в консоль нечего нету,он заходит в этот метод контроллера но без data.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.
Попробуйте использовать formData.append('_method', 'PATCH') до метода axios.post. и всё)
спс за ответы! Удачи всем!)

Comment: Спасибо большое, то, что я искал)